# C++ Win32 Listen for global keybinds

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, hotkeys

I am trying to implement global hotkeys on Windows in my C++/Qt application. I used RegisterHotKey, which surprisingly worked and I can see that pressing the combination triggers my event, but since I did not know any other way, I just used a loop, which now blocks my windows and stops it from ever showing up.

You can find my code below. How do I listen for this combination? There certainly has to be another way.

```
void set_win32_keys(MainWindow *mwin) {
    HWND main_hwnd = (HWND)mwin->winId();
    RegisterHotKey(main_hwnd, 2, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT, 0x32 /*2 key*/);
    MSG *msg;
    msg = new MSG();
    BOOL b_ret;
    while ((b_ret = GetMessage(msg, main_hwnd, 0, 0)) != 0) {
      if (b_ret == -1) {
        qDebug() << "Error";
      } else {
        if (msg->message == WM_HOTKEY) {
          mwin->new_screenshot();
          qDebug() << msg;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @kfsone I'm sorry, I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I listen to the system hot key bound to the app main window?

Many system events can be caught at main window native event handler. And the original author post actually binds to main window. The below should process the requested message:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
      // ... snip ...
      bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result) override;
      // ... snip ...
};

bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result)
{
    MSG* pMsg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);

    if (pMsg->message == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
       // process pMsg->wParam / lParam etc.

       // the intended action
       this->new_screenshot();
    }

    // call the parent, could be QWidget::nativeEvent
    return QMainWidow::nativeEvent(eventType, message, result);
}
```

Because of assumption that `mwin` has `QMainWindow*`:

```
HWND main_hwnd = (HWND)mwin->winId();
RegisterHotKey(main_hwnd, 2, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT, 0x32 /*2 key*/);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually works, is quite easy to understand is really straight-forward.

Answer (score 4):

Shameless plug: I have written a library for Qt that provides global hotkeys in a cross-platform manner - and allows the usage of for example `QKeySequence` to create the hotkey. It allows you to use a `QKeySequenceEdit` to let the user enter his own shortcut:

https://github.com/Skycoder42/QHotkey

Example:

```
//MainWindow constructor:
QHotkey *hotkey = new QHotkey(Qt::Key_2, Qt::ControlModifier | Qt::ShiftModifier, true, this);
connect(hotkey, &QHotkey::activated, this, &MainWindow::new_screenshot);
```

And that's it! Hope it helps

Comment: Developing Qt a bit more. Good!

Comment: I've been searching through all kinds of hotkey libraries for Qt and never found yours. This is by far the best documented and easy-to-get library so far. I will try it as soon as I can. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: @mkocs Your welcome :D I created it just recently, that could be a reason.

Comment: @Felix I tried it yesterday and it works beautifully. Good job with that library :)